# How can I protect my project's source code from being used in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

So I made a project in Eclipse with Java and one of my classmates asked me to send him the project. I want to send him a non-functional project meaning that he can see the source code but cannot run it. How can I do that?
The project consists of a login window where users have to give their login details. I made this connecting Java with Mysql.....

I thought that one possible solution is to make an external jar which asks for a password and include it into my project...Or to connect to a web server and ask for authentification.......

Comment: Note the they can always copy the code and run it anyway. You could use a [trap street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_street).

Comment: When he can see the code, then he can execute it

Comment: I know that he can somehow copy it into another project, BUT: this person is very dumb so he can't do that........if he simply copies it to another project than he will get errors and he won't be able to make it work...

Comment: So, the person is unable to build a program from source code and run it. He/she wants source code. You're ready to send him/her the source code, but don't want him/her to be able to run it. What's the problem then exactly? You've said he/she wouldn't be able to build a program from source code and run it. That said, what's the point of asking for source code if you can't use it? And what's the point of sending source code if you don't want him/her to use it? Why not just say "No"?

Comment: He thinks that if I send him the source code he can use it as his own project as is....or with only little modifications(note that I am not refferring to code mofications, he will only modify the names of my functions, variables - because he is only able to do that...)

Comment: There is a word for that: cheating, or, worse, plagiary. Don't facilitate that, just say no.

Comment: ^^ that. Don't do it. If this is an academic environment then this will end very badly.

Comment: I know :( but he wants me to send it.....I don't know what to do

Comment: Open source or closed source that is the question.